# Should be a Piecewise function, a ConditionalExpression or Indeterminate, but it is a number

Tags: evaluation, symbolic, piecewise, rule

I apologize in advance for the lack of focus of my question. Consider the function:

```
f[x_, y_] := x/(x + y);
```

`f[0,0]` evaluates to Indeterminate, as it should be. However, the following code evaluates to 0:

```
f[0, a] (* evaluates to 0 *)
```

So if you do:

```
f[0, a] /. {a -> 0}  (* evaluates to 0 *)
```

you also get 0, even though this code seems to me equivalent to `f[0,0]`.

I would have expected `f[0, a]` to be evaluated to a `ConditionalExpression` such as:

```
ConditionalExpression[0, a != 0]
```

or a `Piecewise` function such as:

```
Piecewise[{{0, a != 0}}, Indeterminate]
```

but not to 0, as it is. Is there any way I can make Mathematica behave more cautiously (i.e. as I expect, described above). I know about `GenerateConditions`, but I have not been able to use it in this kind of case. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Define `f` to be `f[x_, y_] := ConditionalExpression[x/(x+y), x+y != 0]`. — Somewhere on site there is a discussion of something like `x/x /. x -> 0` or `0/x /. x -> 0`, which is related to what’s going

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelE2 !! That certainly solves my problem! Don't you want to post it as an answer? P.S. Defining the function as Piecewise[{{x/(x + y), x + y != 0}}, Indeterminate] is more convenient for me, since I can operate with it (e.g. computing Jacobians) without getting errors. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general one may define a function based on an expression `expr` so that restrictions on the domain of `expr` won't be lost during partial evaluation with either of the following:

```
Piecewise[{{expr, FunctionDomain[expr, {vars}]}}, Undefined]
Piecewise[{{expr, FunctionDomain[expr, {vars}]}}, Indeterminate]
```

The first is automatically converted to a `ConditionalExpression`.

Example:

```
Block[{x, y},
 f[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{x/(x + y), x + y != 0}}, Undefined]
 ]
```

> ```
> (*  ConditionalExpression[x/(x + y), x + y != 0]  *)
> ```